# Factor (string) to Numeric in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, types

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information), is it possible to convert a String field to Numeric in PostgreSQL. For instance,

```
create table test (name text);

insert into test (name) values ('amy');
insert into test (name) values ('bob');
insert into test (name) values ('bob');
insert into test (name) values ('celia');
```

and add a field that is

```
 name  | num
-------+-----
 amy   | 1
 bob   | 2
 bob   | 2
 celia | 3
```

Comment: What about `insert into test (name) values ('☃');`?

Comment: What does the number represent? Are you looking for the string's ASCII character representation? Or do you want to assign a character an arbitrary number like a = 1?

Comment: @jcern there is no meaning of the numbers as long as they can distinguish the names.

Comment: @MattBall I need an automatic procedure to convert the name field to numeric. The real table has thousands of rows.

Comment: @Rock so something like a hash of the `name` would suffice?

Comment: @MattBall yah, if that works.

Comment: Your example seems to indicate duplicate strings? You want to enter complete dupes into the table? This is generally a bad idea ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Actually there are other fields such as IDs. To simplify the problem, I've only shown the `name`.

Comment: You may have over-simplified the example. It is essential to the problem whether strings and / or rows are unique or not. I provided an answer for the question as is - dealing with duplicates.

Comment: Your example appears to be well suited to the `dense_rank` window function, since you want the same field to be the same number.

Comment: @CraigRinger Can you give an example?

Comment: @Rock See answer. I think it's a bad idea; this feels like one of those cases where you're asking how to accomplish a solution you've decided on, when you should really be asking about the underlying problem (why you want to add these numbers to each row). A hash or proper generated key via a lookup table is almost certainly wiser. Nonetheless, it'll do what you want.

Comment: @CraigRinger It is really I need some unique identifier for each row. So it can either be a number or hash. Thank you for opening the other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How 'bout a hash, [such as md5](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html), of `name`?

```
create table test (name text, hash text);

-- later

update test set hash = md5(name);
```

If you need to convert that md5 text to a number: [Hashing a String to a Numeric Value in PostgresSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809381/hashing-a-string-to-a-numeric-value-in-postgressql)

Comment: @Rock: md5 hashes are not unique. While a collision is very unlikely, there is no guarantee. Amy could end up with the same hash as Bob.

Answer (score 4):

The most effective "hash"-function of all is a [**`serial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) primary key - giving you a unique number like you wished for in the question.

I also deal with **duplicates** in this demo:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE string (
  string_id serial PRIMARY KEY
 ,string    text NOT NULL UNIQUE    -- no dupes
 ,ct        int NOT NULL DEFAULT 1  -- count instead of dupe rows
);
```

Then you would enter new strings like this:
([Data-modifying CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) requires PostgreSQL 9.1 or later.)

```
WITH x AS (SELECT 'abc'::text AS nu)
   , y AS (
   UPDATE string s
   SET    ct = ct + 1
   FROM   x
   WHERE  s.string = x.nu
   RETURNING TRUE
   )
INSERT INTO string (string)
SELECT nu
FROM   x
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM y);
```

If the string `nu` already exists, the count (`ct`) is increased by 1. If not, a new row is inserted, starting with a count of 1.

The `UNIQUE` also adds an index on the column `string.string` automatically, which leads to optimal performance for this query.

Add additional logic (triggers ?) for `UPDATE` / `DELETE` to make this bullet-proof - if needed.

Note, there is a super-tiny race condition here, if two concurrent transactions try to add the same string at the same moment in time. To be absolutely sure, you could use `SERIALIZABLE` transactions. More info and links under this [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11532550/939860).

#### [Live demo at sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/e5e6d/2).

Comment: Thank for this great answer, always as complete as your other answers, Erwin.

Answer (score 1):

If they are all single characters, you could do this:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN num int;
UPDATE test SET num = ascii(name);
```

Though that would only return the character for the first letter if the string was more than a single character.

Comment: Thank you Jcern. Actually they are NOT single characters. It's a `text` field.

Answer (score 1):

The exact case shown in your request can be produced with the [`dense_rank` window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html):

```
regress=# SELECT name, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY name) FROM test;
 name  | dense_rank 
-------+------------
 amy   |          1
 bob   |          2
 bob   |          2
 celia |          3
(4 rows)
```

so if you were adding a number for each row, you'd be able to do something like:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN some_num integer;

WITH gen(gen_name, gen_num) AS 
   (SELECT name, dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY name) FROM test GROUP BY name)
UPDATE test SET some_num = gen_num FROM gen WHERE name = gen_name;

ALTER TABLE test ALTER COLUMN some_num SET NOT NULL;
```

*however* I think it's much more sensible to use a hash or to assign generated keys. I'm just showing that your example can be achieved.

The biggest problem with this approach is that inserting new data is a pain. It's a ranking (like your example shows) so if you `INSERT INTO test (name) VALUES ('billy');` then the ranking changes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Craig. At least this is another way to accomplish it and maybe useful in other cases.