# Oracle to postgres migration

Tags: postgresql

We use oracle built in function - outln_edit_pkg.generate_signature - to generate 32 byte hash signature for up to a 32k-1 sized string value passed to it.
Reference:

- http://psoug.org/reference/outln_edit_pkg.html
- http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_ault_hash_data_warehouse.htm

Wondering what would be the replacement when we move to Postgres. 
I found below https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html documentation related to hashing but not sure which one to use.

Looks like md5 hashing with 32 bit is one option - [Hashing a String to a Numeric Value in PostgresSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809381/hashing-a-string-to-a-numeric-value-in-postgressql) -   but not 100% sure

Comment: Either `md5` or the `pgcrypto` hash functions should work fine.