# In Postgres, is it faster to use DENSE_RANK() and RANK() over the MD5 of a string?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hash, ranking

I'm using DENSE_RANK() to produce PRIMARY KEY candidate columns from other TEXT columns.

E.g.

`SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY title) AS pk_id;`

I'm aware than sorting text is slower than sorting integers, so I had the idea to convert the text to an integer format before ranking.  (following advice from: [Hashing a String to a Numeric Value in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809381/hashing-a-string-to-a-numeric-value-in-postgresql))

My method currently uses a temporary table, as I'm trying to ensure that `md5(...)` only runs once per row, and I can't be sure of that if I simply put the `md5(...)` call within the `OVER(...)` part.  What I do instead is: 1) create a temporary table using `md5(...)`, then 2) I run `DENSE_RANK()` over this other table instead, thus creating my primary key column.

But I thought I'd ask here, to know for sure: Would it actually be faster to use `md5(...)` within the `OVER(...)` parentheses?  I.e.

`SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY 'x'||substr(md5($1),1,16))::bit(64)::bigint) AS pk_id;`
`

My question can also be worded as follows: Would the Postgres query optimiser be good enough to recognise that the "to bigint" conversion is a static procedure?  In particular, I'm worried that the `md5(...)` conversion would run once per comparison (O(n log n)), rather than once per row (O(n).

PS: One or two hash collisions are okay for my use case.

Comment: `SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY title) AS pk_id` - This query is incomplete. Please add the execution plans for both queries to the question.

Comment: I would use row_number() so every row gets a different number, dense_rank is capable of returning the same number for 2 or more rows. Also you can order by any combination of columns , not sure you gain much by using md5