# Postgresql Convert bit varying to integer

Tags: postgresql, bit

Searched the postgresql docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-bitstring.html for information on converting bit varying to integer

But couldnt' find any info.

```
select '011111'::bit(4)::varbit(4)::integer as varbit
```

Appreciate your response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way:

```
SELECT b, lpad(b::text, 32, '0')::bit(32)::int
FROM (
    VALUES
     ('01'::varbit)
    ,('011111')
    ,('111')
 ) t (b);
```

Result:

```
b      | lpad
-------+------
01     |    1
011111 |   31
111    |    7
```

Related answer:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

Comment: Thanks but my intention was that I have a column of type bit varying and I wanted to convert it to integer

Comment: @Pals: The cast `::bit(32)` was missing in my first draft. Fixed and added a demo.

Comment: It is working only for 32 bits. What is the solution if I have more than 32 bits?

Comment: @Pals: How would you convert that to a 4-byte integer, which cannot hold more than 32 bit of information? You *did* ask for [`integer`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html). The next step is `bigint` with 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say our table has 3 columns and 3 rows. We can simulate it with:

```sql
select *
from (
    values ('row1', 1::int, 12::bit(8)::varbit), 
           ('row2', 2::int, 23::bit(8)::varbit), 
           ('row3', 3::int, 34::bit(8)::varbit)
) as T(A,B,C);
```

As you can see, first columns is `varchar` , second is `int` and the third is `varbit`.

Let's convert third column to `int`:

```sql
select C::bit(8)::int 
from (
    values ('row1', 1::int, 12::bit(8)::varbit), 
           ('row2', 2::int, 23::bit(8)::varbit), 
           ('row3', 3::int, 34::bit(8)::varbit)
) as T(A,B,C);
==C==
  12
  23
  34
```

The point is, you have to convert it to `bit(n)` first, then you can convert `bit(n)` to `varbit`. The same thing is also true for `int` to `varbit`.