# Understanding difference between int literal vs int parameter in PL/pgSQL function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, function-parameter

I have a function to left pad bit stings in PostgreSQL 9.5:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lpad_bits(val bit varying) 
RETURNS bit varying as
$BODY$
  BEGIN return val::bit(32) >> (32-length(val));
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

which works fine:

```
 # select lpad_bits(b'1001100111000');
        lpad_bits
 ----------------------------------
 00000000000000000001001100111000
 (1 row)
```

My problem is when I try to add a parameter to change the amount of padding:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lpad_bits(val bit varying, sz integer default 1024) 
  RETURNS bit varying as
$BODY$
  BEGIN return val::bit(sz) >> (sz-length(val));
  END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

The function is now broken:

```
# select lpad_bits(b'1001100111000', 32);
```

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "sz"
> LINE 1: SELECT val::bit(sz) >> (sz-length(val))
>                 ^
> QUERY:  SELECT val::bit(sz) >> (sz-length(val))
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function lpad_bits(bit varying,integer) line 2 at RETURN
> ```

I have stared at the [bitstring documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html) and [PL/pgSQL function documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-declarations.html#PLPGSQL-DECLARATION-PARAMETERS), am simply not seeing what is fundamentally different between these two implementations.

Comment: It seems that it is impossible to use variable in the type definition. There are to alternatives: 1) Using dynamic SQL; 2) `lpad(val::text, sz, '0')::bit varying;`

Comment: @Abelisto - OK, but I wanted to know *why*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why?

PL/pgSQL executes SQL queries like ***prepared statements***. [The manual about parameter substituion:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html)

> Prepared statements can take parameters: values that are substituted
>   into the statement when it is executed.

Note the term ***values***. Only actual values can be parameterized, but not key words, identifiers or type names. `32` in `bit(32)` *looks* like a value, but the modifier of a data type is only a "value" internally and can't be parameterized. SQL demands to know data types at planning stage, it cannot wait for the execution stage.

You *could* achieve your goal with dynamic SQL and `EXECUTE`. As **proof of concept**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lpad_bits(val varbit, sz int = 32, OUT outval varbit) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT $1::bit(%s) >> $2', sz)  -- literal
   USING val, sz - length(val)                     -- values
   INTO outval;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT lpad_bits(b'1001100111000', 32);
```

Note the distinction between `sz` being used as ***literal*** to build the statement and its second occurrence where it's used as ***value***, that can be passed as parameter.

#### Faster alternatives

A superior solution for this particular task is to just use **`lpad()`** like [@Abelisto suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40290807/understanding-difference-between-int-literal-vs-int-parameter-in-pl-pgsql-functi#comment67840614_40290807):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lpad_bits2(val varbit, sz int = 32)
  RETURNS varbit AS
$func$
SELECT lpad(val::text, sz, '0')::varbit;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

(Simpler as plain SQL function, which also allows *function inlining* in the context of outer queries.)

Several times faster than the above function. A minor flaw: we have to cast to `text` and back to `varbit`. Unfortunately, `lpad()` is not currently implemented for `varbit`. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html)

> The following SQL-standard functions work on bit strings as well as
>   character strings: `length`, `bit_length`, `octet_length`, `position`, `substring`, `overlay`.

**`overlay()`** is available, we can have a cheaper function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lpad_bits3(val varbit, base varbit = '00000000000000000000000000000000')
  RETURNS varbit AS
$func$
SELECT overlay(base PLACING val FROM bit_length(base) - bit_length(val))
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Faster if you can work with `varbit` values to begin with. (The advantage is (partly) voided, if you have to cast `text` to `varbit` anyway.)

Call:

```
SELECT lpad_bits3(b'1001100111000', '00000000000000000000000000000000');
SELECT lpad_bits3(b'1001100111000',  repeat('0', 32)::varbit);
```

We might ***overlaod*** the function with a variant taking an integer to generate `base` itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lpad_bits3(val varbit, sz int = 32)
  RETURNS varbit AS
$func$
SELECT overlay(repeat('0', sz)::varbit PLACING val FROM sz - bit_length(val))
$func$  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT lpad_bits3(b'1001100111000', 32;
```

Related:

- [Postgresql Convert bit varying to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020950/postgresql-convert-bit-varying-)
- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

Comment: Good answer - I did not recognize the distinction between `32` as a value and `bit(32)` as a type.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The parser does not allow a variable at that place. The alternative is to use a constant and trim it:

```
select right((val::bit(128) >> (128 -length(val)))::text, sz)::bit(sz)
from (values (b'1001100111000', 32)) s(val,sz)
;
              right               
----------------------------------
 00000000000000000001001100111000
```

Or the `lpad` function as suggested in the comments.