# Other way to cast varbit to int? And bigint?

Tags: postgresql, casting

This function is a workaround ... nothing with **better performance**?

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION varbit_to_int(v varbit) RETURNS int AS $f$
  SELECT CASE bit_length(v)
    WHEN 1 THEN v::bit(1)::int
    WHEN 2 THEN v::bit(2)::int
    WHEN 3 THEN v::bit(3)::int
    ...
    WHEN 30 THEN v::bit(30)::int
    WHEN 31 THEN v::bit(31)::int
    WHEN 32 THEN v::bit(32)::int
    ELSE NULL::int
  END
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Same problem for bigint:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION varbit_to_bigint(p varbit) RETURNS bigint AS $f$
  SELECT CASE bit_length($1)
    WHEN 1 THEN $1::bit(1)::bigint
    WHEN 2 THEN $1::bit(2)::bigint
    WHEN 3 THEN $1::bit(3)::bigint
    ...
    WHEN 62 THEN $1::bit(62)::bigint
    WHEN 63 THEN $1::bit(63)::bigint
    WHEN 64 THEN $1::bit(64)::bigint
    ELSE NULL::bigint
  END
$f$ LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Using many times in loops seems CPU-wasteful, only to avoid "cannot cast type bit varying to integer" error.  Maybe an external C-language  library do this and other useful castings.

---

**NOTICE**  `select b'101'::bit(64)::bigint != b'101'::bigint;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested a couple of variants (for `bigint` only) with built-in functionality and this variant with [`OVERLAY()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) turned out **fastest** in my local tests on Postgres 11:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION varbit2bigint2(b varbit)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
SELECT OVERLAY(bit(64) '0' PLACING b FROM 65 - bit_length(b))::bigint
$func$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

#### Other candidates:

*Note the different conversion of empty bitstrings (`''`) to `0` vs. `NULL`. Adapt to your needs!*

Your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION varbit2bigint1(b varbit)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
  SELECT CASE bit_length($1)
   WHEN  1 THEN $1::bit(1)::bigint
   WHEN  2 THEN $1::bit(2)::bigint
   WHEN  3 THEN $1::bit(3)::bigint
   WHEN  4 THEN $1::bit(4)::bigint
   WHEN  5 THEN $1::bit(5)::bigint
   WHEN  6 THEN $1::bit(6)::bigint
   WHEN  7 THEN $1::bit(7)::bigint
   WHEN  8 THEN $1::bit(8)::bigint
   WHEN  9 THEN $1::bit(9)::bigint
   WHEN 10 THEN $1::bit(10)::bigint
   WHEN 11 THEN $1::bit(11)::bigint
   WHEN 12 THEN $1::bit(12)::bigint
   WHEN 13 THEN $1::bit(13)::bigint
   WHEN 14 THEN $1::bit(14)::bigint
   WHEN 15 THEN $1::bit(15)::bigint
   WHEN 16 THEN $1::bit(16)::bigint
   WHEN 17 THEN $1::bit(17)::bigint
   WHEN 18 THEN $1::bit(18)::bigint
   WHEN 19 THEN $1::bit(19)::bigint
   WHEN 20 THEN $1::bit(20)::bigint
   WHEN 21 THEN $1::bit(21)::bigint
   WHEN 22 THEN $1::bit(22)::bigint
   WHEN 23 THEN $1::bit(23)::bigint
   WHEN 24 THEN $1::bit(24)::bigint
   WHEN 25 THEN $1::bit(25)::bigint
   WHEN 26 THEN $1::bit(26)::bigint
   WHEN 27 THEN $1::bit(27)::bigint
   WHEN 28 THEN $1::bit(28)::bigint
   WHEN 29 THEN $1::bit(29)::bigint
   WHEN 30 THEN $1::bit(30)::bigint
   WHEN 31 THEN $1::bit(31)::bigint
   WHEN 32 THEN $1::bit(32)::bigint
   WHEN 33 THEN $1::bit(33)::bigint
   WHEN 34 THEN $1::bit(34)::bigint
   WHEN 35 THEN $1::bit(35)::bigint
   WHEN 36 THEN $1::bit(36)::bigint
   WHEN 37 THEN $1::bit(37)::bigint
   WHEN 38 THEN $1::bit(38)::bigint
   WHEN 39 THEN $1::bit(39)::bigint
   WHEN 40 THEN $1::bit(40)::bigint
   WHEN 41 THEN $1::bit(41)::bigint
   WHEN 42 THEN $1::bit(42)::bigint
   WHEN 43 THEN $1::bit(43)::bigint
   WHEN 44 THEN $1::bit(44)::bigint
   WHEN 45 THEN $1::bit(45)::bigint
   WHEN 46 THEN $1::bit(46)::bigint
   WHEN 47 THEN $1::bit(47)::bigint
   WHEN 48 THEN $1::bit(48)::bigint
   WHEN 49 THEN $1::bit(49)::bigint
   WHEN 50 THEN $1::bit(50)::bigint
   WHEN 51 THEN $1::bit(51)::bigint
   WHEN 52 THEN $1::bit(52)::bigint
   WHEN 53 THEN $1::bit(53)::bigint
   WHEN 54 THEN $1::bit(54)::bigint
   WHEN 55 THEN $1::bit(55)::bigint
   WHEN 56 THEN $1::bit(56)::bigint
   WHEN 57 THEN $1::bit(57)::bigint
   WHEN 58 THEN $1::bit(58)::bigint
   WHEN 59 THEN $1::bit(59)::bigint
   WHEN 60 THEN $1::bit(60)::bigint
   WHEN 61 THEN $1::bit(61)::bigint
   WHEN 62 THEN $1::bit(62)::bigint
   WHEN 63 THEN $1::bit(63)::bigint
   WHEN 64 THEN $1::bit(64)::bigint
   ELSE NULL::bigint
  END
$func$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;  -- no STRICT modifier
```

Left-padding the text representation with '0':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.varbit2bigint3(b varbit)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
SELECT lpad(b::text, 64, '0')::bit(64)::bigint
$func$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

Bit-shifting before the cast:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION varbit2bigint4(b varbit)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$func$
SELECT (bit(64) '0' || b << bit_length(b))::bit(64)::bigint
$func$  LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1769ae4c9ef5fe2e70cf54dcaebcd8b4)*

Related:

- [Postgresql Convert bit varying to integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020950/postgresql-convert-bit-varying-to-integer)

#### Your feedback

> It is not worst, it is faster!
>
> ```
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE select 
>   varbit_to_bigint(osm_id::bit(64)::varbit) 
> from planet_osm_point limit 10000 ;
> -- Planning time: 0.697 ms
> -- Execution time: 1133.571 ms
>
> EXPLAIN ANALYZE select 
>   lpad(osm_id::bit(64)::varbit::text, 32, '0')::bit(64)::bigint 
> from planet_osm_point limit 10000;
> -- Planning time: 0.105 ms
> -- Execution time: 26.429 ms
> ```

You show a **`STRICT`** modifier with the `bigint` variant of the function in the question (not sure why it differs from the `integer` variant). If that represents the function you actually tested, I expect most of the observed performance difference is due to that added **`STRICT`** modifier preventing **function inlining**. [Quoting the Postgres Wiki:](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions)

> if the function is declared `STRICT`, then the planner must be able to
>   prove that the body expression necessarily returns `NULL` if any
>   parameter is null. At present, this condition is only satisfied if:
>   every parameter is referenced at least once, and all functions,
>   operators and other constructs used in the body are themselves `STRICT`.

That seems to hurt your function badly - while my winner seems unaffected, and the other two variants are even ~ 10 % faster. Same fiddle with `STRICT` functions:

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=d6c24d452cc1146eec30b59de6c599e3)*

Related:

- [Function executes faster without STRICT modifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8455177/function-executes-faster-without-strict-modifier)

I suggest you re-test with and without `STRICT` modifier to see for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, I commented "seems CPU-wasteful (...) external C-language"  but only requested "better" in the introduction, it is vague. I am editing to "better performance". PS: your solution is the worst in terms of performance, but is elegant...A C-language implementation of `lpad(varbit)` perhaps will be suficient for better performance.

Comment: Yes, SCRICT is horrible (!), I used only to avoid NULLs...  I remove `strict` and now Execution times are near the same: 3480.135 ms (lpad) vs 3547.097 ms. The big difference is about planning: 1.420 ms vs 0.141 ms.

Comment: @Peter: Have you considered my new variant with `OVERLAY()`? Should be considerably faster than either. (Also, 1 ms of planning pales in comparison with  3500 ms of execution, doesn't it? If planning time matters, consider a plpgsql variant ...)

Comment: Perfect (!), your  bit-shifting   `varbit2bigint4()` function is the faster, and OVERLAY have near same performance.