# Postgres 9.4: fast way to convert color from hex to rgb representation

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have hex representation color, for sample `#112233` stored in Postgresql 9.4

Need convert this representation to `rgb(17,34,51)` in pl/pgsql function

Any Ideas to convert it fastest way?

Comment: What type is it stored as?

Comment: table field type is text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This uses [Erwin's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/330315) to convert a hex value to an integer value:

```
with colors (hex_code) as (
  values ('#112233'), ('#203040')
)
select 'rgb('||
       ('x'||substr(hex_code,2,2))::bit(8)::int||','||
       ('x'||substr(hex_code,4,2))::bit(8)::int||','||
       ('x'||substr(hex_code,6,2))::bit(8)::int||')'
from colors
;
```

Not sure if that is the fastest way, but I can't think of a different one. The `select` expression can be moved into a function without problems.

SQLFiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/3720