# Create big integer from the big end of a uuid in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design, types, casting, uuid

I have a third-party application connecting to a view in my PostgreSQL database. It requires the view to have a primary key but can't handle the UUID type (which is the primary key for the view). It also can't handle the UUID as the primary key if it is served as text from the view.

What I'd like to do is convert the UUID to a number and use that as the primary key instead.  However,

```
SELECT x'14607158d3b14ac0b0d82a9a5a9e8f6e'::bigint
```

Fails because the number is out of range.

So instead, I want to use SQL to take the big end of the UUID and create an int8 / bigint. I should clarify that maintaining order is 'desirable' but I understand that some of the order will change by doing this.

I tried:

```
SELECT x(substring(UUID::text from 1 for 16))::bigint
```

but the x operator for converting hex doesn't seem to like brackets. I abstracted it into a function but

```
SELECT hex_to_int(substring(UUID::text from 1 for 16))::bigint
```

still fails.

How can I get a bigint from the 'big end' half of a UUID?

Comment: but ... views can't have a `primary key`.

Comment: We are doing an override in the third-party app to assign a primary key to the view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is all very shaky, both the problem and the solution you describe in your self-answer.

First, a mismatch between a database design and a third-party application is always possible, but usually indicative of a deeper problem. Why does your database use the `uuid` data type as a PK in the first place? They are not very efficient compared to a `serial` or a `bigserial`. Typically you would use a UUID if you are working in a distributed environment where you need to "guarantee" uniqueness over multiple installations.

Secondly, why does the application require the PK to begin with (incidentally: views do not have a PK, the underlying tables do)? If it is only to view the data then a PK is rather useless, particularly if it is based on a UUID (and there is thus no conceivable relationship between the PK and the rest of the tuple). If it is used to refer to other data in the same database or do updates or deletes of existing data, then you need the exact UUID and not some extract of it because the underlying table or other relations in your database would have the exact UUID. Of course you can convert all UUID's with the same `hex_to_int()` function, but that leads straight back to my point above: why use `uuid`s in the first place?

Thirdly, do not mess around with things you have little or no knowledge of. This is not intended to be offensive, take it as well-meant advice (look around on the internet for programmers who tried to improve on cryptographic algorithms or random number generation by adding their own twists of obfuscation; quite entertaining reads). There are 5 algorithms for generating UUID's in the `uuid-ossp` package and while you know or can easily find out which algorithm is used in your database (the `uuid_generate_vX()` functions in your table definitions, most likely), do you know how the algorithm works? The claim of practical uniqueness of a UUID is based on its 128 bits, not a 64-bit extract of it. Are you certain that the high 64-bits are random? My guess is that 64 consecutive bits are less random than the "square root of the randomness" (for lack of a better way to phrase the theoretical drop in periodicity of a 64-bit number compared to a 128-bit number) of the full UUID. Why? Because all but one of the algorithms are made up of randomized blocks of otherwise non-random input (such as the MAC address of a network interface, which is always the same on a machine generating millions of UUIDs). Had 64 bits been enough for randomized value uniqueness, then a `uuid` would have been that long.

What a better solution would be in your case is hard to say, because it is unclear what the third-party application does with the data from your database and how dependent it is on the uniqueness of the "PK" column in the view. An approach that is likely to work if the application does more than trivially display the data without any further use of the "PK" would be to associate a `bigint` with every retrieved `uuid` in your database in a (temporary) table and include that `bigint` in your view by linking on the `uuid`s in your (temporary) tables. Since you can not trigger on `SELECT` statements, you would need a function to generate the `bigint` for every `uuid` the application retrieves. On updates or deletes on the underlying tables of the view or upon selecting data from related tables, you look up the `uuid` corresponding to the `bigint` passed in from the application. The lookup table and function would look somewhat like this:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table(
    tempint bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    internal_uuid uuid);
CREATE INDEX ON temp_table(internal_uuid);

CREATE FUNCTION temp_int_for_uuid(pk uuid) RETURNS bigint AS $$
DECLARE
    id    bigint;
BEGIN
    SELECT tempint INTO id FROM temp_table WHERE internal_uuid = pk;
    IF NOT FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO temp_table(internal_uuid) VALUES (pk)
        RETURNING tempint INTO id;
    END IF;
    RETURN id;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT;
```

Not pretty, not efficient, but fool-proof.

Comment: Good advice. While you aim for "fool-proof" you should also [defend against race conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324). Either way, the solution would exhibit *terrible* performance ("not efficient" as you put it), the temp table has to be rebuilt for every session with single inserts. Should rather be a regular table or better yet, just add the `serial` to the underlying table and use it directly. No more function needed. Truly fool-proof and best performance.

Answer (score 15):

#### Fast and without dynamic SQL

Cast the leading 16 hex digits of a UUID in text representation as [bitstring `bit(64)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) and cast that to `bigint`. See:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

Conveniently, **excess hex digits to the right are truncated** in the cast to `bit(64)` automatically - exactly what we need.

Postgres accepts various formats for input. Your given string literal is one of them:

```
14607158d3b14ac0b0d82a9a5a9e8f6e
```

The default text representation of a UUID (and the `text` output in Postgres for data type `uuid`) adds hyphens at predefined places:

```
14607158-d3b1-4ac0-b0d8-2a9a5a9e8f6e
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html)

> A UUID is written as a sequence of lower-case hexadecimal digits, in
> several groups separated by hyphens, specifically a group of 8 digits
> followed by three groups of 4 digits followed by a group of 12 digits,
> for a total of 32 digits representing the 128 bits.

If input format can vary, strip hyphens first to be sure:

```
SELECT ('x' || translate(uuid_as_string, '-', ''))::bit(64)::bigint;
```

Cast actual [**`uuid`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html) input with `uuid::text`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5a84d3574e93433605bdbfb0e714d922)*

Note that Postgres uses *signed* integer, so the `bigint` overflows to negative numbers in the upper half - which should be irrelevant for this purpose.

#### DB design

If at all possible add a [**`bigserial`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column to the underlying table and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `bit()` function to parse a decimal number from hex literal built from a substr of the UUID:

```
select ('x'||substr(UUID, 1, 16))::bit(64)::bigint
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8d423/2)

Answer (score 1):

Solution found.

`UUID::text` will return a string with hyphens. In order for `substring(UUID::text from 1 for 16)` to create a string that `x` can parse as hex the hyphens need to be stripped first.

The final query looks like:

```
SELECT hex_to_int(substring((select replace(id::text,'-','')) from 1 for 16))::bigint FROM table
```

The `hext_to_int` function needs to be able to handle a `bigint`, not just `int`. It looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hex_to_int(hexval character varying)
  RETURNS bigint AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   result  bigint;
BEGIN
 EXECUTE 'SELECT x''' || hexval || '''::bigint' INTO result;
 RETURN result;
END;
$BODY$`
```