# Generate new UUID per row depending on gaps in existing time series

Tags: sql, postgresql, gaps-and-islands, postgresql-12

I have a `table1` with timestamps, grouped by an added “Period ID”:

```
Period ID (uuid)    Created At (timestamptz)
  A                 2017-04-11 11:13:47.997+00
  A                 2017-04-11 14:42:51.843+00
  B                 2017-05-21 15:18:12.973+00
  B                 2017-05-21 15:28:41.054+00
  B                 2017-05-21 15:28:57.577+00
  C                 2017-06-11 22:48:00.637+00
  D                 2017-07-15 14:45:52.343+00
  D                 2017-07-15 14:47:53.343+00
  E                 2017-08-25 16:22:57.612+00
  F                 2017-09-16 00:10:18.577+00
```

I need to create a new ID “Period ID 2” as a subset of Period ID, such that:

1. A UUID is populated in the first row in the new column “Period ID 2”.
2. A new Period ID 2 is generated for each different Period ID value (Ex: All timestamps with Period ID “A” can have same “Period ID 2”, timestamps for  Period ID “B” can all have the same “Period ID 2”. BUT the “Period ID 2” for A and B cannot be the same )
3. For records with the same “Period ID”, if the difference between consecutive timestamps is more than 10 mins, then a new “Period ID 2” should be generated.  (Example :  for the records with “Period ID” = B, the interval between the first and second timestamp is more than 10 minutes, so a new “Period ID 2” will be generated for the second value. The interval between 2nd and 3rd is less than 10 mins, so the 2nd and 3rd records will have the same “Period ID 2”).

So, the output should be like this:

```
Period ID (uuid)    Created At (timestamptz)    Period2 (uuid)
  A                 2017-04-11 11:13:47.997+00      1
  A                 2017-04-11 14:42:51.843+00      2
  B                 2017-05-21 15:18:12.973+00      3
  B                 2017-05-21 15:28:41.054+00      4
  B                 2017-05-21 15:28:57.577+00      4
  C                 2017-06-11 22:48:00.637+00      5
  D                 2017-07-15 14:45:52.343+00      6
  D                 2017-07-15 14:47:53.343+00      6
  E                 2017-08-25 16:22:57.612+00      7
  F                 2017-09-16 00:10:18.577+00      8
```

I can add the column, but I am not sure how to populate it. I looked into the following flow: `ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE FUNCTION` (for trigger function), `CREATE TRIGGER`, ... But I wasn’t able to query it properly. Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please provide data as formatted *text*, not as image.

Comment: Sorry about that. I’ve added the tables in formatted text.

Comment: Since you mention triggers, do you need to update these regularly whenever new data is inserted into the table? Would it need to merge period2 ids if a new entry was inserted within a >10min span that separate two groups but now does no longer?

Comment: Yes, these need to be updated regularly when new data is inserted. I didn’t quite understand the second part of the question.

Comment: Say you insert `A  2017-04-11T11:11`, then `A  2017-04-11T11:26`. You'll get two separate period2 values (since the two are 15 min apart). Now you insert `A  2017-04-11T11:19`. How many period2's will you have now (with 8 and 7 min distances)? I.e. will you need to update the period2 values of other, already existing, rows, to merge them?

Comment: if they are 7-8 mins apart, then both the entries should have same period 2 IDs

Comment: You mean all three rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you ask:

```sql
SELECT period_id, created_at, md5(period_id::text || grp)::uuid AS period_id2
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(*) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (PARTITION BY period_id ORDER BY created_at) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT *, (created_at - lag(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY period_id ORDER BY created_at)) > interval '10 min' AS step
      FROM  tbl
      ) sub1
   ) sub2;
```

Or with just a single subquery - albeit less readable:

```sql
SELECT period_id, created_at
     , md5(period_id::text || count(*) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (PARTITION BY period_id ORDER BY created_at))::uuid AS period_id2
FROM  (
   SELECT *, (created_at - lag(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY period_id ORDER BY created_at)) > interval '10 min' AS step
   FROM  tbl
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4eb4137594b539d05fad327611a9e8b3)*

I chose a deterministic way to generate UUIDs. So the Nth group within the same `period_id` always gets the same, reproducible UUID.

Basic explanation for this query technique:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

About `md5()` and UUID:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)
- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)

Maybe you don't actually need UUIDs to begin with? I see them used a lot without need. See:

- [PostgreSQL using UUID vs Text as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836749/postgresql-using-uuid-vs-text-as-primary-key/33838373#33838373)

#### Persist as table?

If you are at liberty to replace the existing table, just creating a new one will be fastest:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl2 AS
SELECT period_id, created_at
     , md5(period_id::text || count(*) FILTER (WHERE step) OVER (PARTITION BY period_id ORDER BY created_at))::uuid AS period_id2
FROM  (
   SELECT *, (created_at - lag(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY period_id ORDER BY created_at)) > interval '10 min' AS step
   FROM  tbl
   ) sub;
```

If you write to the table, `period_id2` for all involved `period_id` have to be recalculated. In case of `INSERT` only the ones later than the new `created_at` (plus the new row itself). With all the added bloat and vacuum cost to the table, this gets expensive quickly.

Maybe consider a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html). But at some point, if the write costs outweigh read cost, it will be cheaper ***not*** to persist `period_id2` at all and compute it on the fly. Heavily depends on actual read and write patterns.

Comment: *`count(*) FILTER (WHERE step)`* - oh, clever grouping!

Comment: Given OP wants this to be updated when there are inserts in the table, do you suggest creating this as a (materialised) view?

Comment: @Bergi: That depends on actual (undisclosed) write patterns. Either way, all contained `period_id2` have to be recalculated if any row for the parent `period_id` changes in a way that messes with steps. We can narrow it down to all rows `>= created_at` of the written row, unless an update or delete took something away, too ...