# Should I use a UUID as PK + index by (user_id, UUID), or a single composite (user_id, UUID) PK?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, database-design, primary-key

A relative noob building a Postgres SQL database to track data by user, where every row is guaranteed to have a `uuid` as well as `user_id` assigned, and with most queries being by `user_id` and optional `uuid`.

I am wondering if there is an "obviously better approach" between:

1. A single `uuid` PK, accompanied by a `user_id`+`uuid` index
2. A composite `user_id`+`uuid` PK

Feels like both would get the job done, however not sure if there is a clear winner between the simplicity of the `uuid` PK and efficiency of having the purpose-built index for retrieval by user/uuid, or getting both at once with the composite PK (wouldn't these be "physically located" closer by user -if that matters-, at perhaps some extra insertion complexity, although the index would also carry it?)

Answer (score 2):

If that's all the DB has to do:

> ... most queries being by `user_id` and optional `uuid`.

Then option 2 should serve best:

> A composite user_id+uuid PK

(Uniqueness of `uuid` is not enforced this way!)
With leading `user_id`.

But I somehow doubt that's the complete picture. DB optimization always depends on the complete situation.

Typically, you also have queries on just `uuid`. (Or FK constraints pointing to just that column? Or other design elements working with the PK of the table?) Then option 1 is clearly better. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

Also, only use the type `uuid` if you actually need it. Else, `bigint` is more efficient. See:

- [PostgreSQL using UUID vs Text as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836749/postgresql-using-uuid-vs-text-as-primary-key/33838373#33838373)

To increase locality of data per user, it should help to [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) the table on an index with leading `user_id` from time to time. See:

- [Optimize Postgres query on timestamp range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13998139/optimize-postgres-query-on-timestamp-range/14007963#14007963)

Comment: This is for an online app where I expect to have many users, each with their own data (i.e. more users than data per user), so data locality felt pretty important. I would expect to basically add more indices based on queries (e.g. timestamp-based, but again per user).

Comment: It should help to `CLUSTER` the table on an index with leading `user_id` from time to time. I added a link.

Comment: "Then option 2 should serve best: A composite user_id+uuid PK" but that would allow anomalies where the same `uuid` is used with a different `user_id`

Comment: @Charlieface: That's true. Another possible downside. I added a warning. (The actual role of the uuid is not entirely clear. *"every row is guaranteed to have a uuid"* leaves room for interpretation.)