# Use data type uuid or varchar(36) for my UUID column?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, uuid

I'm using PostgreSQL in my project. The primary key column in my table is a character type with length of 36. I generate guids in the backend and store them in the table. Do I need to change the column type as uuid? Can it have the same performance?

Comment: `uuid` = 128-big integer so it is smaller than e.g. `VARCHAR(36)`. I'd expect a small positive impact on performance (how much depends on several factors) and I feel confident saying it won't hurt performance compared to using a text type. Conclusion: no reason not to use the `uuid` type.

Comment: "I generate guids in backend and store them in the table" Unrelated but I'd rather do data-related jobs using data tools and not the opposite - generate uuids in the database and then do whatever is there to do in the backend with them.

Comment: UUIDs contain 32Hex digits which for storage compresses to 16bytes (2hex digits/byte) and without the dashes (-). However, not all character strings can compose a uuid. A valid uuid must satisfy the regular expression `<uuid column> ~ '^[0-9A-Fa-f\-]'` or similar expression.  If your existing satisfy that condition then by all means use type `uuid`. As for performance, it is* as likely to improve* as it is otherwise.

Comment: Postgres can generate UUID for you. Versions 13 and above see [UUID FUnctions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-uuid.html). For versions 12 and prior first install the `uuid-ossp` extension, then use `uuid_generate_v4()` function.

Comment: The answer to this question was given ca. 20 centuries ago in ancient Rome - "Lex specialis derogat legi generali", i.e. a private rule supersedes (derogates) the general one. So nowadays use the specialized `uuid` type (and its "rules") rather than the general `text` one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store UUIDs as data type [**`uuid`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html), not as `varchar` or `text`. That would require more space in RAM and on disk, be slower to process and more error prone. See:

- [What is the optimal data type for an MD5 field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/3684)
- [PostgreSQL using UUID vs Text as primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33836749/postgresql-using-uuid-vs-text-as-primary-key/33838373#33838373)