# hex string to integer

Tags: sql, encoding, int, hex, netezza

how to convert a hex string to integer? Postgres way of doing this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/3206440)

Adding sample input and output tables below.

**table1**

```
+---------+
| hex_val |
+---------+
| 00ff    |
| 00b0    |
| 8000    |
| 0050    |
+---------+
```

**output**

```
+---------+
| int_val |
+---------+
|     255 |
|     176 |
|   32768 |
|      80 |
+---------+
```

Comment: @JohnHC - that answer is for PostgreSQL

Comment: Sorry, saw Postgres in the question, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string_to_int to do this, specifying 16 as the base as the second parameter:

```
select string_to_int('8000',16);
 STRING_TO_INT 
---------------
         32768
(1 row)
```

This is documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.1/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_ntz_sql_extns_conversion_funcs.html).