# Equivalent of UTL_RAW.BIT_OR of Oracle in Postgresql

Tags: oracle, postgresql, oracle11g, postgresql-9.4

```
select utl_raw.bit_or('32','3') from dual;

Result : 33
```

I'd like to know how to get similar output in postgresql. Please help.

Comment: are you sure its 33?..

Comment: @VaoTsun: looks like those are hex numbers

Comment: yes - it looks so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`utl_raw.bit()` apparently uses hex values.

Postgres supports bit operations only on [bit strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html) which means those hex input values need to be converted to a bit string, then you can use the built-in functions.

Based on [Erwin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/330315) to convert hex to bit, you can do this:

```
select (x'32'::bit(8) | x'03'::bit(8));
```

This returns

```
00110011
```

Note the leading `0` for the second value. `x'3'::bit(8)` will return `00110000` but with a leading `0` the conversion to a bit string results in `00000011`. See the linked answer for more details on that.

To get a hex number back, we must first convert it into an integer, then we can use `to_hex()` on it:

```
select to_hex((x'32'::bit(8) | x'03'::bit(8))::int)
```

returns `33`

Comment: `select to_hex((x'32' | x'03')::int);` got same after your hint on (16) - thank you

Comment: I was trying to do bit or on two hexadecimals like this to_hex() | to_hex(). thanks -a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin function for that.

It should not be too hard to write that in the procedural language of your choice. For PL/pgSQL you could use the `get_byte()` and `set_byte()` functions.