# Convert DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE BigSql to Postgres/Greenplum

Tags: sql, hash, greenplum

I'm migrating a table with a column field that contains query's from BigSql to Greenplum.

In the old query I have a funcition `DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE(Field,0,10)` that returns an Integer value.

I tried to use the function md5 in greenplum and casting it, but I receive error.

Can you please help me? Do you know a function in PostgreSql/Greenplum that works like the `DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE` and returns a Integer value?

Comment: You can convert the hex value from `md5()` to a bigint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164

Comment: Don't post code in comments. **[edit]** your question by clicking on the [edit] link below it.

Comment: I tried the solution purposed in the link.Anyway: I need Integer values from 0 to 9 and casting to bit i cannot reach this interval. DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE(Field,0,10) VS the function above, don't return the same values. Any suggestions? Thank you so much! –

Comment: Someone who can help me?