# Migrate SQL Server functions to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, plpgsql

How can I do these same conversions that are written in SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

These are the data I receive:

```
@AVLData_GPSElement_Longitude   @AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude
D224E31D                        F8C95DB9
```

This is the conversion that is written in SQL Server.

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, @AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2))), 1, 3) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, @AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2))), 4, 7)

SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, @AVLData_GPSElement_Longitude, 2))), 1, 3) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARBINARY, @AVLData_GPSElement_Longitude, 2))), 4, 7)
```

and the result it gives is the following:

```
@MOPO_LAT        @MOPO_LON
-12.102099900   -76.933449900
```

So far I have managed to do this conversion so far:

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARBINARY, AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)::INTEGER ::VARCHAR FROM 1 FOR 3) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARBINARY, AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)::INTEGER ::VARCHAR) FROM 4 FOR 7);
```

but my big question arises in this function:

```
CONVERT (VARBINARY, @AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)
```

I don't know how to translate it because I don't find much information about it.
I am working on conversions of teltonika fm920 gps equipment.
I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? The official documentation shows the functions available, and googling the function name plus the RDBMS name gives lots of info...

Comment: So far I have managed to do this conversion :         
 SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARBINARY, AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)::INTEGER ::VARCHAR FROM 1 FOR 3) + '.' + SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARBINARY, AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)::INTEGER ::VARCHAR) FROM 4 FOR 7);  but my big question arises in this function  CONVERT(VARBINARY, @AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)  In postgres it has a bytea function but I don't know how to pass it the value 2

Comment: [edit] it all into your question... and clarify specifically which part of the conversion you are stuck with.

Comment: That's a very ugly way to do that conversion even in T-SQL, incidentally, and since it seems to assume negative numbers I'm not even sure it's reliable. `SELECT CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(BINARY(4), @AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 2)) / 10000000.0` would be cleaner (this can then be converted/formatted further if fewer decimals are desired). It's basically just parsing the number as hex and dividing, which is probably easier in Postgres than the string manipulation too (but I don't know it well enough to say).

Comment: Jeroen Mostert   How could I do something similar in postgres.

Comment: Apparently it's [far from trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8316164/4137916). `('x' || lpad(AVLData_GPSElement_Latitude, 8, '0'))::bit(32)::int` should do the trick (and then dividing by `10000000.0` has much the same result).

Comment: It might be easier if you described what you're trying to do, rather than how you're currently doing it. I'm having trouble following the SQL code, and there's probably a better way than a straight conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is first converting hex to an integer. `F8C95DB9` is `-121020999`. [Use the technique here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/14660). Stick an `x` on the front so [`bit(32)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html) will cast it as hex, then cast that to a 32 bit integer.

```
select ('x'||'F8C95DB9')::bit(32)::int4
    int4    
------------
 -121020999
```

Then divide by 10000000.0.

```
select ('x'||'F8C95DB9')::bit(32)::int4 / 10000000.0 as lat;
         lat          
----------------------
 -12.1020999000000000
```

And at that point I would stop and leave further formatting to the display layer.

*Note: If you're working with Latitude and Longitude, consider [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/)*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I get the following message  "operator does not exist: variable character * integer 42883"