# convert actual string and characters to numbers in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way i could convert an actual string to a number in postgresql

i have record stored in db and below is an example of unique identifier found in each record.

`d895774d-7b91-4adc-bfba-f1264e5aae04`

I want to store this record in another database but i would want to generate another unique number for each transaction/line

Is there a way i can convert this `d895774d-7b91-4adc-bfba-f1264e5aae04` to some number.
like this actual numbers `13693660123082308270370273012321321312321`

```
select 'd895774d-7b91-4adc-bfba-f1264e5aae04' as id
```

Comment: remove the dashes, then convert the hex value to [a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First convert the string into a table of single characters (the `from` clause);
Then select the digits 'as is', `a` as `10`, `b` as `11` and so on (the `case` expression);
Finally aggregate into a string (`string_agg`)
skipping the `-` characters (`where` clause).

```sql
select 
    string_agg(case when c between '0' and '9' then c else (ascii(c) - 87)::text end, '') 
 from unnest(string_to_array('d895774d-7b91-4adc-bfba-f1264e5aae04', null)) c
 where c <> '-';
```

Result: `13895774137119141013121115111015126414510101404`

- **Edit**

```sql
select 
  td.date, 
  (
   select string_agg(case when c between '0' and '9' then c else (ascii(c) - 87)::text end, '') 
   from unnest(string_to_array(td.id, null)) c
   where c <> '-'
  ) as id
from table_d td;
```

Comment: Nice. how do i incorporate this in my query `select date, id from table_d`

Comment: Thanks, that one will do

Comment: @OmariVictorOmosa: if you need that a lot, you should create a function out of that to make your life easier