# Convert Hexadecimal to date formating utc-5 Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Hello friends I am trying to convert a hexadecimal to date that must be in utc-5 format peru time

this is the function with which I try to do this conversion:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.hex_timestamp(
    text)
    RETURNS timestamp without time zone
    LANGUAGE 'sql'

    COST 100
    IMMUTABLE STRICT 
    
AS $BODY$
select 
    (to_timestamp(('x' || lpad($1, 16, '0'))::bit(64)::bigint / 1000.0))::timestamptz at time zone 'utc-5'
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.hex_timestamp(text)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

and this is my hex value:

```
0000017B3DB65648
```

However, the time is not correct since it takes me one day ahead of the current date and the time is not correct either

```
13/08/2021 04:12:45
```

I would like you to show me the correct date and time with Peruvian time, this is the correct time that it should show

```
12/08/2021 23:23:53
```

thanks for your help

Comment: [Edit] the question and explain how the hex value designates a point in time. An erroneous conversion function isn't of any help there.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using my hex-to-decimal conversion from this related answer:

- [Convert hex in text representation to decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316164/convert-hex-in-text-representation-to-decimal-number/8335376#8335376)

This converts hex `0000017B3DB65648` to decimal `1628827965000`:

```
SELECT ('x' || lpad('0000017B3DB65648', 16, '0'))::bit(64)::bigint;  -- 1628827965000
```

That number seems to represent the number of milliseconds since the Postgres epoch (2000-01-01 00:00:00). See:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

```sql
SELECT to_timestamp(1628827965000 / 1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';         -- '2021-08-13 06:12:45'
     , extract('epoch' FROM timestamp '2021-08-13 04:12:45') * 1000;  -- 1628827965000
```

Your desired result is `2021-08-13 23:23:53`, that's exactly an interval of `19:11:08` later (19 hours, 11 minutes, 8 seconds).
That's `69068000` milliseconds, the difference between `1628897033000` and  `1628827965000`.

And that **does not seem to make sense**. We can't get to your desired result with adjustment for time zones.

Please check your question for typos and tell us what the hex number is supposed to represent ***exactly***.